# Image bigger in browser than it is set in css

Tags: html, css, image, size

I put the image on my page:

```css
.image img {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.image {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="gallery/1.png" />
</div>
```

Real size of image is height: 200px and width: 300px.

The problem is that image is bigger in browser. I had set on my css file the real dimensions, and it was still higher. Where's the problem? Is that with browser?

Comment: where is your css ?

Comment: Please provide css.

Comment: you can also use box-shadow rather than border its works the same

Comment: I added my css to a first post

Comment: may be some css properties is overlapping it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the width and the height inside the image tag

```
<img src="gallery/1.png"  height="200" width="300" />
```

this is your code, and it works fine:

```css
.image img {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="image">
<img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried your code and it works perfect, something is override it

Comment: you can try add !imortant :

.image img {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 200px !important;
    width: 300px !important;
}

Comment: you need to add all the css file

Comment: Okay, I found the problem. I've got set in my windows options scale=125%. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

first of all apply this property to img tag

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

with this all img will be show with their  actual witdh;

second check in your code if define

```
img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

with this code image will be stretched if image container width is bigger then image actual height.

Hope this will help you :)